# Bind working but on not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get error on img load through on, but it doesn't work

```
$(document).on("error","#someid img",
               function(){
                  console.log("Image load error through On");
              });
```

but the similar works with 'bind'

```
$("#someid img").bind("error", function() {
                         console.log("Image load error through bind");
                      });
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The method .on() was added in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: what's the version of jquery in the document?

Comment: i have the 1.7.1 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `error` event doesn't bubble, so you can't use event delegation to capture it at the `document` level.

The only way to capture it will be to bind directly to the element.

---

You can determine this by using the `.bubbles` property on the `event` object in your `.bind()` handler.

```
$("#someid img").bind("error", function(event) {
    console.log(event.bubbles); // false
});
```

Comment: okay, bind doesn't work on html added to the dom after the event is bound.

Comment: @MuditTuli: Right. You're going to have to bind directly to the elements as you create them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#your_id").error(function () {
     alert("your text")
 })
```

1. .`on()` replaces `.bind(), .live() and .delegate()` after jquery1.7.
2. .on() manages event delegation, bind doesn't.
3. What is [event.delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)?